# How to change math font size inside math environments?

Tags: amsmath, environments, fontsize

Is there any way to change(increase) the math font size inside environments like equation, align etc.. globally without changing the \intertext{} and \text{} size. and without affecting the numbering of equations?

Comment: What about inline math material (as opposed to display-math material): Should it use the enlarge font size of display math, or should it employ the unmodified font sizes?

Comment: The short answer is no.  You might redefine \intertext and \text to add \normalsize, but anything inside a group with a font size change will otherwise be affected.